# Graphical representation of weekly spending

Tags: data-visualization, self-study, histogram

What is the correct graphical representation for these data of weekly spending (in dollars) on soft drinks for 20 people:

```
12,13,17,21,24,24,26,27,27,30,32,35,37,38,41,43,44,46,53,58
```

I want to separate the data into 5 bins:

```
10-20(f=3),    20-30(f=6),    30-40(f=5),    40-50(f=4),    50-60(f=2)
```

and I title axis: "Weekly spending (dollar amount)".

Which one would be more appropriate for y axis?  (For which I put `f=3,6,5,4,2`.)

1. Frequency per \$1 spent
2. Frequency per \$10 spent

Comment: mmhmm intresting! GEK 2900!

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that a [graphical model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model) is a very different thing than a graph of your data.  What you are doing is plotting a histogram.  I would drop the `f#` notation and just put the range of values for each bin on the x-axis, or more simply, place tick marks between the bins with the boundary values marked.  Then I would put "frequency" as the title of your y-axis.  Note that most software should do this for you by default.

Answer (score 1):

If the homework was to create a histogram, then I would go with @gung 's approach. If the homework was to represent the data graphically, I wouldn't use bins - I would use a density plot with some sort of smoother; another possibility is a strip plot, and yet another is a box plot, but there are so few data points that a box plot really isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to choose between them. If I choose $10 for the y-axis, does the 10 mean the range of bins? Or it may mean 10 times the dollars appeared on x axis?

Comment: I suppose per $ spent makes more sense, but both are odd. It's not "frequency per dollar spent" it's "frequency (dollars spent)"